# Cómo contar cuántas veces se repite una palabra en un Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tengo esta parte de código:

```
df2 = df['transcript'].str.contains('eh').value_counts()[True]
print(df2)
```

Pero esto me devuelve el valor de las celdas en las que aparece. Pero si por ejemplo mi valor 'eh' aparece más de una vez en una celda, ¿cómo puedo contar todas las veces que aparece ese valor independientemente si se repite ese mismo valor en una misma celda?

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Puedes utilizar el método `.str.count()` para contar el número de ocurrencias de un `string` adentro de cualquier columna de tipo `string`

```
df2 = df['transcript'].str.count('eh')
```

Eso te devolverá por cada fila de `transcript` el número total de ocurrencias de `eh`

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me ha sido de gran valor!!

Comment: @sergioizquierdo, Buen día, si la respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas.